# mysql varchar with utf8mb4 maximum character storing capacity

Tags: php, mysql, database, utf-8

I have created one table in mysql for one varchar(8000) field with utf8mb4. Here is the code.

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_content` (
  `id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `content` varchar(8000) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT NULL,
  `insdate` timestamp(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

and one stored procedure to insert records in it as follows.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`ntadmin`@`%` PROCEDURE `nsp_channeldet`(
    IN  cContent VARCHAR(8000) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4
)
    DETERMINISTIC
    COMMENT 'content'
BEGIN
    SET cContent = IF(cContent IS NOT NULL, TRIM(cContent), "");
    INSERT INTO tbl_content (content)
    VALUES (cContent);
END
```

and I am calling as follows.

```
CALL nsp_channeldet("content goes here");
```

It's working fine. I want to know how may character (e.g. maximum characters not bytes) store in this column. If some user enter content in regional language or emojis, when should warning occured (e.g. Data truncated for column)

For my testing I have created on string, which shows me length 10395. It inserts in table without any warning. why???

Here is string

```
ஒரு முதியவர் ஒரு.. ஹோட்டலுக்கு சாப்பிட சென்றார்..!
வெயிலில் வந்த களைப்பு.. அவர் முகத்தில் தெரிந்தது..! அவர் அங்கு ஓர் இடத்தில் அமர்ந்து சர்வரை.. அழைத்து கேட்டார்..! " தம்பி இங்கு சாப்பாடு என்ன விலை..! என்று..!
வெயிலில் வந்த களைப்பு.. அவர் முகத்தில் தெரிந்தது..! அவர் அங்கு ஓர் இடத்தில் அமர்ந்து சர்வரை.. அழைத்து கேட்டார்..! " தம்பி இங்கு சாப்பாடு என்ன விலை..! என்று..!
வெயிலில் வந்த களைப்பு.. அவர் முகத்தில் தெரிந்தது..! அவர் அங்கு ஓர் இடத்தில் அமர்ந்து சர்வரை.. அழைத்து கேட்டார்..! " தம்பி இங்கு சாப்பாடு என்ன விலை..! என்று..!
வெயிலில் வந்த களைப்பு.. அவர் முகத்தில் தெரிந்தது..! அவர் அங்கு ஓர் இடத்தில் அமர்ந்து சர்வரை.. அழைத்து கேட்டார்..! " தம்பி இங்கு சாப்பாடு என்ன விலை..! என்று..!
வெயிலில் வந்த களைப்பு.. அவர் முகத்தில் தெரிந்தது..! அவர் அங்கு ஓர் இடத்தில் அமர்ந்து சர்வரை.. அழைத்து கேட்டார்..! " தம்பி இங்கு சாப்பாடு என்ன விலை..! என்று..!
வெயிலில் வந்த களைப்பு.. அவர் முகத்தில் தெரிந்தது..! அவர் அங்கு ஓர் இடத்தில் அமர்ந்து சர்வரை.. அழைத்து கேட்டார்..! " தம்பி இங்கு சாப்பாடு என்ன விலை..! என்று..!
வெயிலில் வந்த களைப்பு.. அவர் முகத்தில் தெரிந்தது..! அவர் அங்கு ஓர் இடத்தில் அமர்ந்து சர்வரை.. அழைத்து கேட்டார்..! " தம்பி இங்கு சாப்பாடு என்ன விலை..! என்று..!
வெயிலில் வந்த களைப்பு.. அவர் முகத்தில் தெரிந்தது..! அவர் அங்கு ஓர் இடத்தில் அமர்ந்து சர்வரை.. அழைத்து கேட்டார்..! " தம்பி இங்கு சாப்பாடு என்ன விலை..! என்று..!
வெயிலில் வந்த களைப்பு.. அவர் முகத்தில் தெரிந்தது..! அவர் அங்கு ஓர் இடத்தில் அமர்ந்து சர்வரை.. அழைத்து கேட்டார்..! " தம்பி இங்கு சாப்பாடு என்ன விலை..! என்று..!
வெயிலில் வந்த களைப்பு.. அவர் முகத்தில் தெரிந்தது..! அவர் அங்கு ஓர் இடத்தில் அமர்ந்து சர்வரை.. அழைத்து கேட்டார்..! " தம்பி இங்கு சாப்பாடு என்ன விலை..! என்று..!
வெயிலில் வந்த களைப்பு.. அவர் முகத்தில் தெரிந்தது..! அவர் அங்கு ஓர் இடத்தில் அமர்ந்து சர்வரை.. அழைத்து கேட்டார்..! " தம்பி இங்கு சாப்பாடு என்ன விலை..! என்று..!
வெயிலில் வந்த களைப்பு.. அவர் முகத்தில் தெரிந்தது..! அவர் அங்கு ஓர் இடத்தில் அமர்ந்து சர்வரை.. அழைத்து கேட்டார்..! " தம்பி இங்கு சாப்பாடு என்ன விலை..! என்று..!
வெயிலில் வந்த களைப்பு.. அவர் முகத்தில் தெரிந்தது..! அவர் அங்கு ஓர் இடத்தில் அமர்ந்து சர்வரை.. அழைத்து கேட்டார்..! " தம்பி இங்கு சாப்பாடு என்ன விலை..! என்று..!
வெயிலில் வந்த களைப்பு.. அவர் முகத்தில் தெரிந்தது..! அவர் அங்கு ஓர் இடத்தில் அமர்ந்து சர்வரை.. அழைத்து கேட்டார்..! " தம்பி இங்கு சாப்பாடு என்ன விலை..! என்று..!
வெயிலில் வந்த களைப்பு.. அவர் முகத்தில் தெரிந்தது..! அவர் அங்கு ஓர் இடத்தில் அமர்ந்து சர்வரை.. அழைத்து கேட்டார்..! " தம்பி இங்கு சாப்பாடு என்ன விலை..! என்று..!
வெயிலில் வந்த களைப்பு.. அவர் முகத்தில் தெரிந்தது..! அவர் அங்கு ஓர் இடத்தில் அமர்ந்து சர்வரை.. அழைத்து கேட்டார்..! " தம்பி இங்கு சாப்பாடு என்ன விலை..! என்று..!
வெயிலில் வந்த களைப்பு.. அவர் முகத்தில் தெரிந்தது..! அவர் அங்கு ஓர் இடத்தில் அமர்ந்து சர்வரை.. அழைத்து கேட்டார்..! " தம்பி இங்கு சாப்பாடு என்ன விலை..! என்று..!
வெயிலில் வந்த களைப்பு.. அவர் முகத்தில் தெரிந்தது..! அவர் அங்கு ஓர் இடத்தில் அமர்ந்து சர்வரை.. அழைத்து கேட்டார்..! " தம்பி இங்கு சாப்பாடு என்ன விலை..! என்று..!
அதற்கு சர்வர் "50 ரூபாய்" என்றான்..!

பெரியவர் தனது சட்டை பைக்குள்.. கை விட்டு பார்த்து சர்வரிடம் கேட்டார்.. "தம்பி அதற்கும் சற்று.. குறைவாக சாப்பாடு கிடைக்காதா.."?

சர்வர் கோபமாக "யோவ் ஏன்யா இங்க வந்து எங்க உயிர எடுக்கிறிங்க..

இதை விட மலிவான ஹோட்டல் எவ்வளவோ.. இருக்கு அங்க போய் தொலைங்கயா..? என்றான்..!

பெரியவர் சொன்னார்.. "தம்பி தெரியாமல் இங்கு வந்துவிட்டேன்..

வெளியே வெயில் வேறு..அதிகமா இருக்கு.. நான் இனி வேறு ஹோட்டலுக்கு செல்வது சற்று சிரமம்..! என்றார்..!

சர்வர்.. சரி..சரி எவ்வோ பணம் குறைவா வச்சுயிருக்க..! என்று கேட்டான்..!

பெரியவர் என்னிடம் 45 ரூபாய் தான் இருக்கிறது..! என்றார்..!

சர்வர் சரி..தருகிறேன் ஆனால் உனக்கு தயிர் இல்லை சரியா..? என்றான்..!

பெரியவர் சரி என சம்மதித்தார்..!
பெரியவர் சரி என சம்மதித்தார்..!
பெரியவர் சரி என சம்மதித்தார்..!
பெரியவர் சரி என சம்மதித்தார்..!
பெரியவர் சரி என சம்மதித்தார்..!
பெரியவர் சரி என சம்மதித்தார்..!
பெரியவர் சரி என சம்மதித்தார்..!
பெரியவர் சரி என சம்மதித்தார்..!
பெரியவர் சரி என சம்மதித்தார்..!
பெரியவர் சரி என சம்மதித்தார்..!
பெரியவர் சரி என சம்மதித்தார்..!
பெரியவர் சரி என சம்மதித்தார்..!
பெரியவர் சரி என சம்மதித்தார்..!
பெரியவர் சரி என சம்மதித்தார்..!
சாப்பாடு கொடுத்தான்..! பெரியவர் சாப்பிட்டு விட்டு அந்த சர்வரிடம்
50 ரூபாய் கொடுத்தார்..!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 8000 is the maximum number of *characters*, not *bytes*.

Tamil characters are 3 bytes.  Emojis are 4 bytes in utf8mb4.  "Space" is 1 byte.

`LENGTH(col)` gives byte count. `CHAR_LENGTH(col)` gives character length -- this will top out at 8000 in your example.

```
    mysql> SELECT length('வெயிலில் வந்த களை'),
             char_length('வெயிலில் வந்த களை')\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
     length('வெயிலில் வந்த களை'): 47
char_length('வெயிலில் வந்த களை'): 17
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```